# Power PSD in uV^2/Hz via matlab?

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, psd

I would like to know how to make power PSD in microVolt^2/Hz instead of dB/Hz.

```
y=mydata;    
h = spectrum.welch;
Hpsd=psd(h,y,'Fs',Fs,'ConfLevel',0.95);
plot(Hpsd)
```

for the time being, I used this program code for PSD estimation. But based on the example, it will convert to dB/Hz. I need the spectrum in microVolt^2/Hz. is it possible?

Comment: This does not look like a programming problem, rather a technical question. This is probably not the best place to ask this, unless you are struggling to implement a particular piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pwelch` ([www](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/signal/ref/pwelch.html)) will do it.

> if the input data is in volts, the PSD estimate is in units of squared volts per unit frequency.